# Boundary of connected $n$-manifold is connected for $n \geq 2$

Tags: differential-geometry

Are there examples of manifolds of dimension at least $2$ that are connected with disconnected boundary?

Obviously the statement is false in dimension $1$ because you can just use the compact interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Take your favorite $n$-manifold for $n\geq 2$.  Pick $37$ distinct points.   Using the fact that manifolds are Hausdorff, there are $37$ charts which contain the $37$ points which are pairwise disjoint.  Removing those charts give a manifold with $37$ boundary components diffeomorphic to spheres.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can turn your $1$-dimensional counterexample into a counterexample in any dimension. Just take a product of any compact manifold without boundary with $[0,1]$ (think cylinders).

Comment: Ah yes of course.